# snapshoot of widget pyqt5

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

Hi every one I am traying to get a snapshoot of a widget using pyqt5 I am using this code but I can't create an object of the class QScreen
I get an error :

> PyQt5.QtGui.QScreen cannot be instantiated or sub-classed

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap,QScreen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication    
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now()

filename = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

sc=QtGui.QScreen() 

sc.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId()).save(filename, 'jpg')
```

Comment: `app.primaryScreen().grabWindow(0).save(filename, 'jpg')`

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the screen with :

```
sc = app.screens()[0]
```

This [method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screens) returns a list of screens, i assume you want the first (with index `[0]`)